# How to separate accordion functionality from body?

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

When click on accordion its working properly but whole body area is expanding with accordion. I want to expand only accordion not whole HTML body. Please solve this issue.

http://shahfahad.com/app/setting2.html

Answer (score 0):

It is completely natural that when an accordion is expanded, the body will be expanded accordingly. How can you scroll down if you don't want body to expand?

And I think your problem is that you give `background-size: contain;` to `#page-wrapper`. It is confusing you that background image is resizing when body is expanded. So change it like:

```
#page-wrapper {

   /* the rest is the same */

   background-size: cover;
}
```

Hope this helps

Actually, you can totally remove `background-size` property.

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue that your accordion content is overflowing. Just add `height : auto` in the div above this  `<h1>Angular Simple Accordion</h1>`